# Must declare the scalar variable en un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, insert

tengo un procedimiento almacenado que hace un insert y si es exitoso hace un insert y un update. Pero me sale el error:
Must declare the scalar variable

Le puse declare pero me sale error de sintaxis, he visto algunos foros pero ahí establecen el valor de la variable a algo, según entiendo, yo lo que uso son parámetros de entrada.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spStoreTransaction 
@ClientID int, 
@AdviserID int, 
@TheDate datetime, 
@ProductID int,
@QuantityUsed int
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 
     INSERT INTO dbo.Invoice(                    
            ClientID,
            AdviserID,
            TheDate) 
     VALUES ( 
            @ClientID,
            @AdviserID,
            @TheDate) 

    SET TheDate = GETDATE();
    SET @LastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    if @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
        begin
         INSERT INTO dbo.InvoiceDetail(                    
            InvoiceID,
            ProductID,
            QuantityUsed,
            Discount) 
         VALUES( 
            @LastID,
            @ProductID,
            @QuantityUsed,
            @Discount) 

          UPDATE dbo.Product
          SET @Quantity = @Quantity - @QuantityUsed 
          WHERE @ProductID = @ProductID;
       end
END
```

Se que es una duda básica, así que les pido paciencia. Una respuesta directa será apreciada.

***************************************actualización **********************

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spStoreTransaction 
(
    @ClientID int, 
    @AdviserID int, 
    @TheDate datetime, 
    @ProductID int,
    @QuantityUsed int,
    @PercentDiscount decimal(3,0),
    @Discount money,
    @Price money
)
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 
     INSERT INTO dbo.Invoice(                    
            ClientID,
            AdviserID,
            Date) 
     VALUES ( 
            @ClientID,
            @AdviserID,
            @TheDate);
    
    DECLARE @LastId int; --Desconozco si el id de invoice es int, bigint, smallint o el tipo de dato

    SET @TheDate = GETDATE();
    SET @LastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    SET @PercentDiscount = (SELECT PercentDiscount FROM dbo.Product);  
    SET @Price = (SELECT Price FROM dbo.Product);  
    SET @Discount = @PercentDiscount * @Price;

    if @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
        begin
         INSERT INTO dbo.InvoiceDetail(                    
            InvoiceID,
            ProductID,
            Quantity,
            Discount) 
         VALUES( 
            @LastID,
            @ProductID,
            @QuantityUsed,
            @Discount);

          UPDATE dbo.Product
             SET Quantity = Quantity - @QuantityUsed 
          WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;
       end
END
GO
```

Faltaban más cosas como un cálculo y un par de select más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grandes rasgos los errores son:

```
SET TheDate = GETDATE();
```

Te falta la arroba en la sentencia de asignación.

No has declarado la variable LastId por tanto no puedes utilizarla.

Luego en la update debería de ser:

```
UPDATE dbo.Product
      SET Quantity = Quantity - @QuantityUsed 
      WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;
```

Columna = variable, where columna = variable por tanto quitando las arrobas.

El procedure debiera de quedar tal que:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spStoreTransaction 
(
    @ClientID int, 
    @AdviserID int, 
    @TheDate datetime, 
    @ProductID int,
    @QuantityUsed int
)
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON 
     INSERT INTO dbo.Invoice(                    
            ClientID,
            AdviserID,
            TheDate) 
     VALUES ( 
            @ClientID,
            @AdviserID,
            @TheDate);
    
    DECLARE @LastId int; --Desconozco si el id de invoice es int, bigint, smallint o el tipo de dato

    SET @TheDate = GETDATE();
    SET @LastID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    if @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
        begin
         INSERT INTO dbo.InvoiceDetail(                    
            InvoiceID,
            ProductID,
            QuantityUsed,
            Discount) 
         VALUES( 
            @LastID,
            @ProductID,
            @QuantityUsed,
            @Discount);

          UPDATE dbo.Product
             SET Quantity = Quantity - @QuantityUsed 
          WHERE ProductID = @ProductID;
       end
END
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, con lo que me dijiste actualicé el código y funciona.